# select from a table where the dates are different to tha dates in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, qsqlquery

I have some dates in a table and i need a query that the dates in the table are different to the second table, i am intenting with this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1308/2

But it now works

I need for example in the first table:

```
3202024834
3108984111
3118545645
4608389
2631993
9876534
3114568970
```

and in other

```
3202024834
3108984111
3118545645
```

Then the output of the query is:

```
4608389
2631993
9876534
3114568970
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as "Get values in `a` that are not in `b`".  If so, a good way to approach this is with a `left outer join` along with a `where` clause:

```
select a.msisdn
from msisdn a left outer join
     insertados b
     on a.msisdn = b.numero
where b.numero is null;
```

The data is the SQLFiddle doesn't exactly match the data in the question, so the results are a bit different from what is in the question.